# Using multiple Docker Nginx load balancer behind another Nginx load balancer , is this consider as a bad practice?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing

I have one dev/Experimental server in our company, base of our projects is mainly java web apps, so when I want it to move our projects to Docker and scale horizontally to test our stateless servers, I did create docker-compose for each project with their own Nginx load balancer. As a result, I end up with 6 scalable projects and each with one Nginx, so I attached all Nginx to a same network and created main Nginx that attaches to port 80 of host and balance between all the running Nginx.

Problem: I was facing an issue with defined upstream as it was requiring the service to be up and sometimes some of projects were under maintenance and causing Nginx to crash.

Solution: adding seperate Nginx behind my main Nginx helped to run each project whenever I want and use only variable names in Nginx proxy pass so in case of upstream for any java project is down I still be able to run main Nginx.

Each nginx has block of

```
upstream mydocker-service{
  ...
}
```

and main Nginx contains multiple

```
set $stream mydocker-service;
```

used as proxy_pass.

at the end I end up with 6 Nginx responsible for upstream of each project and main Nginx responsible for redirecting request to each Nginx as proxy_pass.

Our projects are not Spring and is not possible to move to Spring either.

So my question is ,  this consider as a bad practice , am I doing it a right way? I there any better solution I can use without going overhead and do kubernetes as I only have one instance?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you should probably make a 1 node swarm.  Swarm will provide the load balancing of your scaled services and you would not need an nginx instance for each project.  To enable swarm all you need is to run `docker swarm init` then you would use `docker stack deploy -c yourcomposefile.yml yourstackname` to deploy your services.  To scale your services you can either use the replicas setting in your compose file or run the `docker service scale yourservicename=3`(to scale your service to 3 replicas).

Comment: ok good idea, already tried that but comes to the point that how can I define stack and load balance it with one Nginx without specifying any Ip address , as I do resolve my Nginx with docker Ip 127.0.0.11 , and use my service names as upstream . is it possible to do it like this in swarm mode ? can you give me some direction ?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  With swarm once you define your service then you should be able to do something like "http://yourswarmhost:serviceport" and swarm will load balance your requests amongst your replicas of that service.  With just one swarm node you can have an nginx in front of your swarm, but it wouldn't be load balancing, it would probably be used to hide the ports or rewrite urls.  You could use traefik to do this as well: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I think I figured out what was an issue. I knew swam is a better way to do that, but I still don't want to give up on Nginx. So my problem was not understanding a difference between overlay network and bridge network in docker , as I am always using one node in my solution, after creating my app Network with overlay driver , everything start working perfectly, now I can remove all the other Nginx as relay on only one Nginx. Also this video helped fair bit . https://youtu.be/t_Tzzucx-oQ  but I still can't run Nginx without stack already been up, that was my main problem.

Comment: so If you have any suggestion for how to run Nginx before have the upstream service up in swarm mode I'm all ears.

Comment: Are you running your nginx in swarm as well?

Comment: I believe your solution of using variables is the way to go there.  You may be able to use nginx healthchecks(https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/), but I would say the variable solution is probably better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222045/discussion-between-betwar512-and-carlos).